# Twitter bootstrap: active list group connected to panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Simple question about Twitter bootstrap, if you look at this example http://eamca.com/tes.html how can I make the active list group get connected with the panel by extending the blue color.

As you see there's small gap between the list menu (left column) and the panel (right column), I need to give blue color when the list group get activated along the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this block to your CSS :

```
.list-group-item.active:after {
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -32px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 42px;
    background-color: #428BCA;
}
```

This will add an `:after` pseudo-element on your active item menu.

- `32px` width is to fit the gap
- `42px` height is to fit the menu item size

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/113676) (based on your code)